# Automorphism group of planar graphs

Tags: symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, planar-graphs, graph-isomorphism, semidirect-product

I am going through [Constructive Approach to Automorphism Groups of Planar Graphs](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.06488v2.pdf) by Klavík et al. It has shown that the automorphism group of a planar graph $G$ is as follows.

$$
\text{Aut} \left(G\right) \cong (\Psi^{m_1}_1 \times \ldots \times \Psi^{m_\ell}_\ell) \rtimes_\varphi \text{Aut} \left(G'\right)
$$

Here $\Psi_i$ is a direct product of symmetric, cyclic and dihedral groups. $m_1, \ldots, m_\ell$ are the sizes of the vertex- and edge-orbits of the action of $Aut(G')$. $G'$ is a $3$-connected planar
graphs with colored vertices and colored possibly oriented edges.

**My questions:**

1. Does $\Psi^{m_i}_i$ mean $m_i$ order direct product of the group $\Psi_i$?
2. Are the sizes of vertex-orbits and edge-orbits of the action of $Aut(G')$ the same?
3. Is every $\Psi_i$ a direct product of one symmetric, one cyclic, and one dihedral group?